# How to Validate `Kendo ComboBox` in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have `Kendo ComboBox` useing it in MVC Project.

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
        .Name("ddl")
        .DataTextField("cName")
        .DataValueField("iID")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "font-size:95%;" })
        .AutoBind(true)
        .Animation(false)
          .Filter(FilterType.StartsWith)
        .DataSource(source =>
        {
            source.Read(read =>
            {
                read.Action("MethodName", "ControllerName");
            });

        })
        )
```

But I want validation for this `ComboBox` on Button Click if no value is selected in `ComboBox` then button click not occur.
Do anyone have any ideas for validating this `ComboBox`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming your button is supposed to submit value you have selected in the ComboBox.

1) store your combobox in a variable `combobox` (optional)

2) validate in following way

```
 $("#submitbutton").click(function() {
               if (combobox.value() != '') {
                   // submit here
               }
        });
```